# speech recognition for Microsoft Access form

Tags: ms-access, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech, speech-to-text

I would like to integrate speech-recognition and text-to-speech technology with an MS Access form, in order to enable the user to use an Access form when the user is not directly in front of his PC,  by using a wireless headset to communicate with the Access form. This would be used in a warehouse environment, to eliminate the need for a PDA bar-code scanner.  The user would need to use his voice to run the Access form commands to look up data  from the form fields as well as to use his voice to input data(SKU’s and numbers) into the form's fields. When the commands to look up the form data are run, I would like the app to convert the text to speech, including reading the message in any dialog box popup windows.    Could the app be calibrated to understand each user’s accent, by having the user speak all of the numbers and letters in the alphabet, during setup?  the app would then associate the accent with the user's log in username. Please advise on the procedure to set this up.  Are there any predeveloped 3rd party add-in apps?  I do know VBA if need be.

Thank you very much in advance, Nathaniel

Comment: I do not think you question is a good fit for SO, but have a look around, for example http://forums.techguy.org/software-development/444108-text-speech-access.html

Comment: To be honest, although I'm all for Access, I wouldn't entertain it in this case, it's really not designed for this type of application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually windows seven has speech recognition built in.  In fact it works quite well with any program, including the office suite.

I'm not sure why are some are suggesting that access would not be appropriate for such an application?

At the end of the day the most challenging problem with using speech recognition is that of allowing the user to mute the button when they speak, or at least allowing and training them having to say "new line", or tab to move to the next field (access cannot know that the user is finished speaking into a particular text box, and in fact no program really can).

Over the years I've used a number of speech recognition programs, but the one in windows seven works quite well now, in fact this post I am making here I am for proof of concept is being written using speech recognition in windows seven, and therefore this post and answer of mine was done using windows speech recognition.

However to be fair, my post is being written and done inside of word, but there's nothing stopped me from having spoken text into an access form.

Comment: My objetive is to be able to have back and forth  verbal commuincation with an MS Access form,  similar to the way people talk to their IPhones.  can the Windows 7 speech recognition and the text to speech tools do that?

Comment: I don't see why  not. Just do a BinGoogle on windows speech api.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about MS Access, but if you have the possibility to use .NET, then there would be an alternative approach to use the Windows Presentation Framework (WPF).

It has basic functionality for both Text-To-Speech (MSDN: [WPF Text To Speech UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc998523.aspx)) and Speech Recognition (MSDN: [SpeechBasics-WPF C# Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855387.aspx). Another tutorial: franksworld.com: [Fun With Speech Recognition in WPF](http://franksworld.com/blog/archive/2009/06/30/11617.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [Mayhem](http://mayhem.codeplex.com/) to possibly wire up this solution.  Mayhem makes it easy to wire up events (user gives voice command) with actions (makes an entry in MS Access).  Take a look at the [demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drvwok9mYbM&feature=youtube_gdata_player) of the Mayhem add-on called [RemoteCommand](http://remotecommand.codeplex.com/) which shows how a user can fire an event by giving a command over the phone or on a PC using Skype that will then trigger an action on another PC.  There are  [a lot of Mayhem add-on's](http://makemayhem.com/Packages/All) and there is [one for MS Office](http://makemayhem.com/Packages/OfficeModules) that may serve your needs, or you might be able to use the [Keypress Module](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3QU5JNB6IQ) to enter the information, or you can easily [develop your own module](http://mayhem.codeplex.com/documentation).  All of this is open source software developed in .Net. The module for accepting voice commands was developed using [VoiceModel](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/).